# Transparent background for TikZ figures in RMarkdown/bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I am including TikZ diagrams in my bookdown project by using code chunks, like

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,engine='tikz',fig.ext=if 
(knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png'}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node (B) at (2,0) {$B$};
  \draw[thick,->] (A) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

and this works fine, apart from the fact that I want the figures to have *transparent backgrounds*. I originally thought that my problem was coming from the conversion to png, but, having enabled caching and looking at the generated pdf files, it seems like these also have white backgrounds.
I've tried various things along the lines of `engine.args=(bg='transparent')`, but nothing seems to work.

How can I get transparent backgrounds? (I'd rather stick to png output if possible, but anything that is web ready is fine by me).

Comment: Can you include a reprex?

Comment: I've just put some example TikZ code in the chunk, but I'm not too sure how much is needed in order to reproduce an entire bookdown project — the specific project that I'm working on can be found here: https://github.com/thosgood/qubit.guide